# BASH: how to redrict to file (didn't find in search)

Tags: bash, redirect

I need to do the following:

```
./$dir_name/bin/calc < m1
```

so calc will run m1.
calc is a calculator which gets an hexa number or operator each time.
m1 is a file looks like this:

```
1
1
+
p
q
```

The result for stdout will be :

```
2
3
```

where 2 is for p
when press q, it sums all operators.

Now I want all that printing to go to a new file res1 insted of stdout.

I tried

```
./$dir_name/bin/calc < m$i >> res1
```

but res1 is still an empty file.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your redirection should work (`cmd < input > output`). Did you check whether your calc tool produces any output?

Comment: Are you sure that `(( i == 1 ))`?

Comment: It should work as you tried it.  There must be some error somewhere else.  Maybe the `m$i` doesn't work as expected or similar.

Comment: verify output of: first `echo m$i`, then `./$dir_name/bin/calc < m$i`, then `./$dir_name/bin/calc < m$i > res1` (no output should be visible), finally `cat res1`. my hunch is you are looking at the res1 in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

It won't fix your bug, bu I propose instead of *appending* more output than one to a file again and again, redirect everything in one step like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  ./$dir_name/bin/calc < m$i
done > res1
```

This way you easily can test what output will come when no redirection is given (just remove the last 6 characters) and then add the redirect.